# Add arguments to Whoops stack frames

Tags: php, error-handling, stack-trace, whoops

This might be a stupid question but I can't really see it in the documentation: is there a config variable (ideally) or an unobtrusive way to add a callback into [Whoops](http://filp.github.io/whoops/) (specifically the `PrettyPageHandler`) so that each frame has its arguments in the info detail area on the right? I'd rather not have to basically copy-and-edit `PrettyPageHandler` just to get it in because I don't want to have issues if I update my version of Whoops in the future.

I've looked into adding a handler to the stack to modify each frame by adding its arguments as a frame comment but ran into problems immediately. Either one of the following is happening:

1. Whoops's `PrettyPageHandler` doesn't show frame comments. Assuming my handler is correctly adding some text to the comment section (I've tried it with just a string rather than trying to get the args list) when I place the handler before the `PrettyPageHandler` in the stack, then `PrettyPageHandler` isn't showing the comments.

   or
2. Whoops can't handle multiple handlers actually doing anything:

   - If I add my handler first, nothing appears to be different (see point 1 above, though)
   - If I add it last I get no Whoops output at all

From the [documentation](https://github.com/filp/whoops/wiki/API-Documentation#wiki-frame) it looks like there's a way to get the arguments from a given frame (see `Frame::getArgs()`), but it would appear that as yet Whoops does not have this implemented in its default handler, or at least not that I can see.

Am I right in that this is pretty much not currently possible without making a whole `PrettyPageHandler` of my own or am I missing something pretty obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that basically this is currently not possible with a stable version of Whoops, but it is available in a feature branch (in unstable state) and planned for later version (possibly as default behaviour, too).

Source:

https://github.com/filp/whoops/issues/15